# How to get the number of elements in protractor nodejs and how to click on particular element having the same xpath

Tags: node.js, selenium, protractor

My scenario is to add a section in a page and perform an action on it.But as there are elements with the same xpath already, webdriver is clicking on first element and the script is failing.So, I want to fetch the existing number of elements having the same xpath and then increase the count by 1 so as to click on the newly added section. Please find the below code and correct me where it is going wrong.(Or) Suggest me any other approach.
Also, please let me know will line no. 9 works if getting the number of elements issue is resolved. Thanks!

Method :

```
this.getElementCount=async function(locator) {
  try {
    console.info('Verifying count for element ' + locator);
    let noOfElements = await element.all(locator).count();
      await console.info('There are ' + noOfElements + 'elements in UI');
      return noOfElements;
  } catch(err) {
      throw err;
  }
}
```

Calling method :

```
var compLocator = element(by.xpath("//div[@title='Test']"));

this.clickOnComp=async function(){
        var elementsCount=getElementCount(compLocator);
        console.info("No. of elements : "+elementsCount);

        if(elementsCount>1){
            var currentEle=elementsCount+1;
            var currentCompLocator=compLocator[currentEle]; // line no.9
            console.info("comp locator :" +currentCompLocator);
            await clickElement(currentCompLocator);
            console.info("Clicked : "+currentCompLocator);
        }
        else{
        await clickElement(compLocator);
        }
        
    }
```

Output :

```
Verifying count for element [object Object]
No. of elements : [object Promise]
(node:13915) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Invalid locator
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with resolving promise with `await`

```
var compLocator = element(by.xpath("//div[@title='Test']"));

this.clickOnComp=async function(){
        var elementsCount=await getElementCount(compLocator); // <-----------------
        console.info("No. of elements : "+elementsCount);

        if(elementsCount>1){
            var currentEle=elementsCount+1;
            var currentCompLocator=compLocator[currentEle]; // line no.9
            console.info("comp locator :" +currentCompLocator);
            await clickElement(currentCompLocator);
            console.info("Clicked : "+currentCompLocator);
        }
        else{
        await clickElement(compLocator);
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your code:

1. **getElementCount()** expects a locator argument by you give a element
2. (Line 9) **compLocator** is an element not an xpath or an element array, you can't use **compLocator[currentEle]**

```
var compXPath = "//div[@title='Test']"
var compLocator = by.xpath(compXPath);

this.clickOnComp=async function(){
  var elementsCount = await getElementCount(compLocator); 
  console.info("No. of elements : "+elementsCount);

  if(elementsCount > 1){
    var currentEle = elementsCount+1;
    var currentCompXPath = compXPath + "/["+ currentEle +"]" // line no.9
    console.info("current Comp xpath :" +currentCompXPath);

    var currentCompLocator = by.xpath(currentCompXPath)
    await clickElement(currentCompLocator);
    console.info("Clicked : "+currentCompLocator);
  }
  else{
    await clickElement(compLocator);
  } 
}
```